# How does the intent in luis work?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

How does it actually work for the intent ? cause in my program i have more than 5 intents and it just shows if i test "hello" it say 0.20 in welcome while the other is just 0 and some have 0.01 or other and adding all of them up doesn't reach 1.0, hence it goes to the welcome intent which is what i expected.

However how does this intent actually work, from the example in the website i was under assumption this is based on percentage based with 1 as the biggest value, just like a logistic regression. However this doesn't seem to be the case since the total of intent value are less than 1.0 so i was thinking this number might be a confidence value or this is just totally different number than what i thought it was ? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you train your LUIS app and test it with an utterance it gives you the confidence level against each trained intent.This score you see is the [degree of confidence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-prediction-score) LUIS has for that result.

To improve the score for an intent you should train your LUIS app with more utterances so that it can differentiate it among other intents.

You can also check out this [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/sigdial2015demo.pdf) by Microsof to understand how LUIS works internally.